# Translating PDEs into proper Fipy syntax

Tags: pde, fipy

I was wondering how to code the following equation in FiPy:

[image: The messy equation in question]

(In case anyone is curious, it comes from [this type of model](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/50/20078.short)). I'm having a little trouble translating the third term on the right side into FiPy code. In the example, A and B are both variables.

I tried something of the form:

```
(ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=chi_A) * (B.getGrad()) / \
 (numerix.sqrt(1 + lambda_ * (B.getGrad())^2))).getGrad()
```

But I suppose one cannot .getGrad() something that is not a variable. I would welcome any help; many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The representation of the term in the question is only an explicit representation. There are two ways to represent the term in an implicit way.

### Single Equation for `A`

Assuming only `A` is being solved for (a single equation for `A`), then the term in question can be represented as a `ConvectionTerm`.

```
ConvectionTerm(coeff=chi_A * B.getGrad() / \
               numerix.sqrt(1 + lambda_ * B.grad.mag**2), var=A)
```

See this [FAQ](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/FAQ.html#what-if-my-term-involves-the-dependent-variable-but-not-where-fipy-puts-it).

### Multiple Equations for `A` and `B`

If `A` is being solved alongside `B` (multiple equations), then it's possible to couple the equations so that the term in question can be a diffusion term with `B` as the variable being solved for (the dependent variable for the term),

```
DiffusionTerm(coeff=chi_A * A / \
              numerix.sqrt(1 + lambda_ * B.grad.mag**2), var=B)
```

The equations for `A` and `B` then need to be coupled,

```
coupled_eqn = eqn_A & eqn_B
```

See [this example](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.coupled.html).

This choice (coupled) is better as the explicit time step restriction on `B` is more stringent than the time step restriction on `A` for the term in question.

### Note

The syntax, `(B.getGrad())^2` in the question is incorrect, it should be `B.grad.mag**2`.

Comment: Dear wd15, this is an elegant answer, and thank you for catching the syntax error. I am still getting an error message when I call the solver. It states, "The coefficient must be rank 0 for a rank 0 solution variable." 
Do you think that this is due to the formulation of the term, or is it a result of using the wrong solving approach?
(Note that I used the "Multiple Equations" method for coding the equation).

Comment: @Snakelet, the "coefficient must be rank 0 ..." error generally means that the coefficient is the wrong shape for the term, i.e. it is a vector instead of a scalar quantity. Maybe you could post your code on pastebin or github for debugging.